# Error while using ProjectCollection.LoadProject Method in c#

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

I'm trying to load an project and build it, but every time I try **to load it** it would throw this error:

```
Microsoft.Build.Exceptions.InvalidProjectFileException: 'The default XML namespace of the project must be the MSBuild XML namespace. If the project is authored in the MSBuild 2003 format, please add xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" to the <Project> element. If the project has been authored in the old 1.0 or 1.2 format, please convert it to MSBuild 2003 format.  C:\Users\mega\source\repos\Logger Builder\Logger Builder\bin\Debug\net472\git\discord-token-logger-zip\logger\logger.csproj'
```

The destination project file looks like this:
[.csproj](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaoqG.png)

and my code is:

```
            var collection = new ProjectCollection();

            var project = collection.LoadProject(@"./git\logger-zip\logger\logger.csproj");
        
            project.Build();
```

Comment: Newer `csproj` files have a different format that's probably incompatible with whatever library you're using.

Comment: @DanielMann the destination project is net472, and I'm using Microsoft.Build.Evaluation

Comment: .NET 4.7.2 is a framework version and is unrelated to the format of the `csproj` file. The library you're using probably doesn't support the newer `csproj` format.

Answer (score 0):

.Net Framework projects typically use the 'legacy' project style. (In Visual Studio 2022 creating a new .Net Framework project will create a legacy style project.)

Legacy style projects are required to use a specific namespace on the `Project` element:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ...>
```

The project you are trying to load is an 'SDK' style project. In an SDK style project the namespace is optional.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
```

The SDK style was introduced circa 2017 to support .Net Core/.Net 5 and later.

My guess is that the project that contains the failing `collection.LoadProject()` call, is using the locally installed .Net Framework version of the Microsoft.Build assembly, which is probably version 4.0.0.0. This version predates the creation of the SDK style project format. (MSBuild 4 is circa 2010.)

If you are using the old library, replace it with the [Microsoft.Build](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Build/17.3.2) NuGet package.

Answer (score 0):

Looking around at [how Roslyn loads solution and projects](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/743d892964a58013bde4ab8daf2845f09896eaf2/src/Workspaces/Core/MSBuild.BuildHost/BuildHost.cs), I discovered that it is probably because you're not setting these environment variables beforehand:

- MSBUILD_EXE_PATH
- MSBuildExtensionsPath
- MSBuildSDKsPath

If you're trying to load the Microsoft.NET.Sdk.* type projects, you could try determining the values for these environment variables, using the `MSBuildLocator` class from the `Microsoft.Build.Locator` package.

The following code extracts them from your most recent Visual Studio version.

```
using Microsoft.Build.Construction; // Package: Microsoft.Build
using Microsoft.Build.Evaluation;   // Package: Microsoft.Build
using Microsoft.Build.Locator;      // Package: Microsoft.Build.Locator

var solutionFilePath = @"PATH TO YOUR SOLUTION FILE";

if (!MSBuildLocator.IsRegistered)
{
    // Locate the right SDK for this particular project; MSBuildLocator ensures in this case the first one is the preferred one.
    var options = new VisualStudioInstanceQueryOptions
    {
        DiscoveryTypes = DiscoveryType.DotNetSdk, 
        WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(solutionFilePath)
    };

    VisualStudioInstance instance = 
        MSBuildLocator.QueryVisualStudioInstances(options)
            .OrderByDescending(o => o.Version)
            .First();

    string dotNetSdkPath = instance.MSBuildPath;
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in new Dictionary<string, string>
             {
                 ["MSBUILD_EXE_PATH"] = Path.Combine(dotNetSdkPath, "MSBuild.dll"),
                 ["MSBuildExtensionsPath"] = dotNetSdkPath,
                 ["MSBuildSDKsPath"] = Path.Combine(dotNetSdkPath, "Sdks")
             })
    {
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(item.Key, item.Value);
    }
}

SolutionFile solutionFile = SolutionFile.Parse(solutionFilePath);
ProjectCollection projects = new ProjectCollection(); // Must be created after setting env variables!

foreach (ProjectInSolution projectInSolution in solutionFile
             .ProjectsInOrder
             .Where(pr => pr.ProjectType is SolutionProjectType.KnownToBeMSBuildFormat))
{
    projects.LoadProject(projectInSolution.AbsolutePath);
}
```

This answer assumes, you're not using Mono or .NET Framework or another version of MSBuild. If you do, just refer to the Roslyn repo as linked above.